# Docker installation on ubuntu raring

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Sorry for this newbie question... :)

I have tried several time to install docker on my linux raring machine but never I succeed to do it correctly.
I am sure this something simple that I should have done but still I don't find it !

I have followed the tutorial :

http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-raring

but when I try to use the command :

sudo apt-get install lxc-docker

I get the following error :

"Not possible to find the package lxc-docker"

so when I try the command : `curl http://get.docker.io | sudo sh`

I get :

```
I hajeangui@jeangui-portable:/usr/local/bin$ curl http://get.docker.io | sudo sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1834  100  1834    0     0   2353      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3869
Ensuring basic dependencies are installed...
Looking in /proc/filesystems to see if we have AUFS support...
Found.
Downloading docker binary to /usr/local/bin...
Upstart script already exists.
Starting dockerd...
Done.
```

But when I run : `sudo docker`

I get this exception : Impossible to launch binary file docker.

I have tried to purge the lxc-docker package but it seems not to be installed...

I don't understand.

Help help :) please.

cheers
Jeangui

Comment: Are you running a 64 bit OS?  `uname -p` should return 'x86_64'

Answer (score 27):

The order of commands should be:

```
sudo sh -c "curl https://get.docker.io/gpg | apt-key add -"
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
```

That is, you first need to add the key for the personal package archive (ppa) and then add that archive to your apt sources.

Please see http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-raring-13-04-64-bit

Comment: Thanks!  I'm apparently illiterate if I'm not on SO!

Comment: I had the same problem, Still i am not able to get the docker in my machine. `Linux arunkumar.gupta 3.8.0-27-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 9 00:19:35 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: The Docker install instructions for Ubuntu 14.04 can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-trusty-1404-lts-64-bit) (spoiler, they're identical to Andy's instructions except the first line, which was replaced with `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9`)

Comment: Tried the first line, getting the error: `$ sudo sh -c "curl https://get.docker.io/gpg | apt-key add -"
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem you need to understand it that Docker only works for 64 bit Ubuntu OS.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-raring linux-headers-generic-lts-raring
sudo reboot
sudo sh -c "wget -qO- https://get.docker.io/gpg | apt-key add -"
sudo sh -c "echo deb http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main\ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
```

But it will show you error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lxc-docker
```

**You will get image of 64 bit and your OS is 32 bit the it won't go and read the image, That why error coming out**

Comment: So the latest docker could work on 64bit Ubuntu OS, now I understand why the docker version is only 1.0.1 on my 32bit ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps

```
> sudo apt update 
> sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
> sudo sh -c "echo deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful stable > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list" 
> curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add –
> sudo apt update 
> sudo apt install docker-ce
```

If you are still facing error refer this blog [Install Docker on Ubuntu, RHEL/CentOS 7 and Windows 10](https://geeksradar.com/install-docker-on-ubuntu-rhel-centos-7-and-windows-10/)